# How to use FileSystem.getPath() as target for a (File-)Writer?

Tags: java, java-io, zip, java.nio.file

I have an app that outputs some files.

Depending on a configuration I Need to put them either in a plain Folder or in a zip file.

I'm trying to use `FileSystem` to decoople the Code actually writing from the actual Destination type.

My problem is that for `Paths` created by Zip-`FileSystems` the method `.tpFile()` is not supported. Therefore I cannot create a `FileWriter` that I can pass to e.g. JaxB.

```
public class FileSystemWriteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileSystem localFileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
        File relativeZipPath = Paths.get("target", "testpath").toFile();
        relativeZipPath.mkdirs();
        URI relativeZipFilePath = Paths.get(relativeZipPath.toString(), "test.zip").toUri();

        URI zipUri = URI.create("jar:"
                + relativeZipFilePath);
        System.out.println(zipUri);
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
        env.put("create", "true");
        try (FileSystem zipFile = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipUri, env)) {
            for (FileSystem fs : Arrays.asList(localFileSystem, zipFile)) {
                Path file = fs.getPath("test.txt");
                System.out.println(file.toAbsolutePath());
/* line 31 */   try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.toFile())) {
                    fileWriter.write("irgend ein Text zum test\nob das so auch geht");
                    fileWriter.flush();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

throws

```
jar:file:///D:/data/scm-workspace/anderes/Test/target/testpath/test.zip
D:\data\scm-workspace\anderes\Test\test.txt
/test.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.toFile(ZipPath.java:597)
    at com.oc.test.filesystem.FileSystemWriteTest.main(FileSystemWriteTest.java:31)
```

What I try to achief is to mashall the JaxB output directly to disk while it is written, not keeping it in Memory until JaxB finished. (My XMLs are rather big so that I may run into an OOME)

**My question:**
How can I open a suitable `Writer` or `OutputStream` fom a `FileSystem` backed by a ZIP file?

*Alternatively*:
What other possibility do I have to hide the real write target (folder vs. ZIP file) from JaxB?

Comment: Really? [`Files.newOutputStream(Path,OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)), [`Files.newBufferedWriter(Path,Charset,OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))…

Comment: @Holger: that worked, thanks! Do you mind to turn that into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most other file system operations, opening an `OutputStream`, `Writer`, or `Channel` can be done via the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/nio/file/Files.html) utilities class.

See, for example

- [`Files.newOutputStream(Path, OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))
- [`Files.newBufferedWriter(Path, Charset, OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) and
- [`Files.newByteChannel(Path, Set<? extends OpenOption>, FileAttribute...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))

but note also the higher-level methods like

- [`Files.write(Path, byte[], OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))
- [`Files.write(Path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>, Charset, OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) and
- [`Files.copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))
  which can copy between different filesystems

But note that for streaming directly into a zip file, using [`ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) atop a `FileOutputStream` may turn out to be more efficient than using the `ZipFileSystem`.